# Show that $x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2$ reducible over Q for any natural number n.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Show that 
$$x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2$$ reducible over Q for any natural number n.

Here is what I did
$$x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2=x^4+2nx^2-n^2x^2+n^2=x^4+2nx^2+n^2-n^2x^2$$
$$=(x^2+n)^2-(nx)^2$$
$$=(x^2+n-nx)(x^2+n+nx)$$

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Can you find an explicit splitting (factorization)? Not many years ago you would have found it easy.

Comment: Did you change your question completely (from $1+x+x^3+x^4$ to $x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2$)?

Comment: @MartinR That and more. he was asking to prove that $x^4+x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over any field which is obviously false as there are such things as algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @GitGud In fact $$x^4+x^3+x+1=(x+1)(x^3+1)=(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)$$ is **reducible** over *any* field, so it is worse than not having taken into account algebraically closed fields.