# Factorize $x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2$ into irreducible polynomials over Q for any natural number n.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Factorize $x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2$ into irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ for any natural number n.
This is an extended version of my previous question [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096864/show-that-x4n2-nx2n2-reducible-over-q-for-any-natural-number-n)

I know if $n=4$, $(x^2+n-nx)(x^2+n+nx)$ is reducible. But how can I show for $n\neq4$?

Comment: Maybe use quadratic formula.

Comment: @Macavity: It is an extended version of that one. I think you should read the question again.

Comment: OK.  Seems all you want is to check if $x^2\pm nx +n$ is reducible if $n \neq 4$?  Then why put the quartic in there and so on?

Comment: To show what am I doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ with $a,b,c\in \mathbb Q$, you just have to check whether the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ has a square root in $\mathbb Q$.

The discriminant of $x^2 \pm nx +n$ is $n(n-4)$, which is an integer, so it has to be the square of an integer to have a square root in $\mathbb Q$. In particular, it has to be non-negative, which means $n \ge 4$ (assuming $n=0$ is not allowed). We have the solution $n=4$; but if $n \ge 5$, then

$(n-3)^2 = n^2-6n+9 = n(n-4) - (2n-9) < n(n-4) < (n-2)^2$

So $n(n-4)$ lies strictly between two adjacent squares, and is therefore not a square.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, solving of equation $x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2=0$:

$\displaystyle x_{1,2,3,4}=\pm \left(\frac{1}{2}(n\pm \sqrt{n-4}\,\cdot\sqrt{n})\right)$

So $x^4+n(2-n)x^2+n^2$ is reducible over Q for $n \ge 4$

Edit: $\color{red}{No - it's\, nonsense.}$

Comment: The roots are *not*  rational numbers!

Comment: @Bernard - Yes, I'm sorry, I wrote nonsense.